# Getting strange error when reading empty cosmos DB container

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am reading the data from cosmos db in azure synase pipelines.
I can read the data successfully if container has some data. If it is empty I am getting below error.
message":"Job failed due to reason: Cannot resolve column name "_ts"

Below is the snapshot of the code.
[image]

Where I am first looking up the database names from a table. Then for each database , I am reading data from each cosmosDB container.
So, currently it is for 4 database. 2 database container has some data and 2 are empty.
Below is the snapshot of execution where last 2 Data flow execution is in error and first 2 are executed succefully.

[image]

Below is the actual error.

[image]
Any one know how to resolve it?
Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify which is the actual error? Which tooling are you using? Any code examples of what you are doing?

Comment: Please edit to show relevant code, along with exact error output (as formatted text, not images of text). Also, you tagged a few different things (including Azure Data Factory) - it would be helpful to know precisely where this error occurs. As written, it's difficult to understand where (or why) this is happening.

Comment: I have edited the description ,kindly please advice. If anything more you need , please let me know.

Comment: untick `Include system columns` in source options and try again It will work but as you don't have any data in container it will throw error as `the result has 0 output columns. Please ensure at least one column is mapped`.

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thanks for the answer. But I need one of the system column hence I ticked it. Is there any other way I could resolve it with Include system columns ticked?